# How do I pipe the output of one command line tool into curl so I can then POST it?

Tags: json, linux, curl, command-line-interface

I'm using `rtl_433` (a command line tool) on a Raspberry Pi to receive data from a home temperature sensor. I get it to output JSON in the Terminal using this command:

```bash
rtl_433 -F json
```

An example of the output in the Terminal is:

```bash
{"time" : "2023-04-12 17:55:57", "model" : "Inkbird-ITH20R", "id" : 9537, "battery" : 90, "sensor_num" : 3, "mic" : "CRC", "temperature_C" : 17.700, "temperature_2_C" : 130.000, "humidity" : 130.000}
```

I need to POST that JSON to my server so I can process it. For debugging of my server app, it's running on a different computer on port 5124 on the same network (`123.123.123.123` is an obfuscated IP):

```bash
rtl_433 -F json | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @- 123.123.123.123:5124
```

Nothing is ever received by my server.

However if I do a quick test to make sure my server is receiving with this:

```bash
echo "{}" | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @- 123.123.123.123:5124
```

It works.

I think I must be piping the output from `rtl_433` wrong but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I think it should work. Another option is to put the JSON in a variable: `json=$(rtl_433 -F json)` and then use `-d "$json"`.

Comment: `-d @-` usually works fine for this purpose, I used it in many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Try like a subcommand. Idk where your output from rtl_433 will be used, but adjust:

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @- 123.123.123.123:5124 **$(rtl_433 -F json)**

Comment: This command does not make sense like this. It should be `-d "$(rtl_433 -F json)"`, not `-d@-`

Comment: really, idk how he will use, it's just a simple example. He needs use a subcommand

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly `rtl_433` is supposed to function, but `-w -` writes its output to `STDOUT`, so this works for me:

```
$ rtl_433  -w - | curl -d @- 127.0.0.1:8888
```

(`netcat` listening on port 8888 – `netcat -l -p 8888`)